If $\omega_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$, how hard can it be to find a non-measurable $\Sigma^1_3$ set of reals?
In his wonderfully titled paper Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away? Shelah showed that if every $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_3$ set of reals is Lebesgue measurable, then $\omega_1$ is an inaccessible cardinal in $L$. More specifically he shows that if there is a real $a$ such that $\omega_1^{L[a]} = \omega_1$, then there is a non-measurable $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_3$ set of reals.

Question. Assume that $\omega_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$. Is there some kind of bound on the Turing degrees of reals $a$ such that there is a non-measurable $\Sigma^1_3[a]$ set of reals?

In a remark Shelah mentions that the proof only really uses two parameters, a $b$ such that $\omega_1^{L[b]} = \omega_1$ and a $c$ such that $\bigcup\{B : B~\text{a Borel set of measure zero which has a code in}~L[c]\}$ is non-measurable.

Is it clear that $a=\emptyset$ doesn't work (e.g. after Sacks forcing once over $L$)?

@NoahSchweber I don't know but I'm asking for a bound that works in any model satisfying that $\omega_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$. Does this argument let you establish something like this?

In $L^{\mathrm{Col}(\omega, \omega_1)}$ all OD sets of reals are measurable, so I don't think there's going to be any reasonable answer to this question.

Reference for the above claim^ https://www.irif.fr/~krivine/articles/Modeles_de_ZF_CRAS.pdf

I thought you were asking about both upper and lower bounds. My comment was towards the idea that there may be no always-applicable lower bound.
